# Latin Character É in QUÉBEC appear as QUÃ‰BEC after read_csv function call

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a psv file to dataframe. When I open the psv file in notepad++ I see, the value as QUÉBEC. But when I open in excel with delimiter as |, the value shows as QU├ëBEC. In the dataframe after using read_csv function- the value shows as QUÃ‰BEC when tried with encoding = cp1252, encoding = latin_1, iso8859-1, iso8859_15. Ultimately, I want the dataframe to have QUÉBEC value.

I have tried with the specified encoding standards, but nothing seems to work.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Specifically, tried all related to Western Europe and Latin.

```
def load_psv_into_df(psv_filename):
    #   This function loads the PSV into the data frame.
    #   Input: PSV File Name
    #   Output: Data frame
    result_df = pd.read_csv (psv_filename, sep='|', encoding='cp1252', 
                   dtype=str, low_memory=False, keep_default_na=False)
    return result_df
```

While using UTF-8 standards, I get the below error message. Same for any encoding standard starting with utf. Please suggest.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 12: invalid continuation byte

Comment: What does Notepad++ show as the encoding? It is shown along the bottom.

Comment: It shows utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

The two most likely encoding options will be `utf-8` and `utf-16le`.  But, like Igaud said, notepad++ will tell you the encoding for sure.

Comment: But when I use utf-8, I get UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 12: invalid continuation byte Error. Please advise.

Comment: Did you try utf-16le?  What encoding did notepad++ say your file was?